# Al subir imagen al servidor con php se sube correctamente, pero en ocasiones no se guarda el nombre de estas en la BD MYSQL

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente problema, realizó para subir una galeria de imagenes, envío los parametros necesarios los cuales son el id de la galeria y el nombre de la imagen, en mi localhost funciona de maravilla, puedo subir multiples imagenes a la galeria sin ningún problema, pero al pasar el proyecto al servidor de hostgator, ejecuto el formulario para subir la imagen a la galería y solo se sube una imagen o en ocasiones no se sube ninguna, que podría ser el problema, adjunto mi código del upload acá debajo

```
 foreach($_FILES["images"]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
 
 if($_FILES["images"]["name"][$key]) {
     $filename = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key]; //Obtenemos el nombre original del archivo
     $source = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key]; //Obtenemos un nombre temporal del archivo

     $directorio = "../../../assets/img/"; //Declaramos un  variable con la ruta donde guardaremos los archivos

     //Validamos si la ruta de destino existe, en caso de no existir la creamos
     if(!file_exists($directorio)){
         mkdir($directorio, 0777) or die("No se puede crear el directorio de extracci&oacute;n");
     }

     $dir=opendir($directorio); //Abrimos el directorio de destino
     $target_path = $directorio.'/'.$filename; //Indicamos la ruta de destino, así como el nombre del archivo

     //Movemos y validamos que el archivo se haya cargado correctamente
     //El primer campo es el origen y el segundo el destino
     if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) {
         $i = new imagen();
         $i->setNombreImagen( $filename);

         if($filename == "" ) {

         }else{
             echo  $i->insertarImagen();
             echo "hola";
         }

  $id = (isset($_REQUEST['id_galeria']) ? $_REQUEST['id_galeria'] : NULL);
         $id = filter_var($id, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

         $gi = new galeriaImagen();

         $retorno = array();
         $conexion=new conexion();
         $consulta=$conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM imagen  where url=:nombre');
         $nombre = $i->getNombreImagen();
         $consulta->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $consulta->execute();
         if($consulta->rowCount()>0){
             $registros = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

             $gi->setIdGaleria($id);
             $gi->setIdImagen(   $registros['id_imagen']);
             echo $gi->insertarGaleriaImagen();
         }
   //      echo "El archivo $filename se ha almacenado en forma exitosa.<br>";
     } else {
         echo "Ha ocurrido un error, por favor inténtelo de nuevo.<br>";
     }
     closedir($dir); //Cerramos el directorio de destino
 }
```

}

espero que me puedan dar una mano ya que no he podido encontrar una solución, la consulta de bd la hago a través de un procedimiento almacenado el cual es el siguiente:

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_insertarImagenes`(IN `_nombre` VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
 
if((SELECT COUNT(*) from imagen as i where _nombre=i.url)>0)then
 
 select "En la base de datos ya existe una imagen con este nombre, dar revisión" as Respuesta; 
                 
 ELSE 
INSERT INTO imagen  VALUES( "",_nombre,now());
SELECT "Imagen insertada  satisfactoriamente" as Respuesta;

        

 END IF;
  

 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Aparte de que no tienes validaciones, no se ve otro posible error. ¿Te has fijado si el problema aparece cuando las imágenes son muy pesadas, algo así como más de 2mb? Porque es el límite que generalmente está configurado en la mayoría de servidores.

Comment: sí, lo he revisado, de hecho una de las imagenes que he logrado subir tiene un peso de 4.36 mb